# Creating Input TextField at precise position on Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Canvas can draw text but it cannot create input textfield. This would mean one have to do it in html but then how can you be sure to position that textfield exactly where you want ?

I want to be able to do this programmatically at runtime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create following HTML structure to place inputbox on canvas.

```
<div id="container" style="width:500px; height:500px; position:relative;">
    <canvas id="drawing-surface" width="500px" height="500px"></canvas>
    <input type="text" style="position:absolute; left=?; top=?;" />
</div>
```

Hope this solves your problem. Replace `left=?` and `top=?` with appropriate positions.

Comment: Thanks and what if I need to move input programmatically ?

Comment: Assuming you are using jquery library, do this. $('#input').css({ top: topPos, left: leftPos});